# Typescript type behaves differently when use as a return value in another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to understand why when I'm declaring a type it behaves in a different way when I use it in another type as the function return value.

```js
type A = {a:boolean};

let a: A = {a: true, b: false} // This is an error Type '{ a: true; b: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'A'

function test(): A {
  return {a: true, b: false}; // This is an error Type '{ a: true; b: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'A'
}

type B = () => A;

const test2: B = () => {
  return {a: true, b: false}; //This works 
}
```

As you can see, adding the b property in the return value works when using the B declaration but not in any of the other declarations

Comment: It's not just you, It **is** a bit confusing. :-) See the answers to the linked question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. It's documented behaviour but to make it worse, it's not in the new TS handbook, only in the old one. And the page that explains it gleefully reports its outdated and offers you a link to the new one which is missing this very important information. It's not easy to even understand even if you decide to read the documentation.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I hope they finally finish that cleanup soon.